# What is the correct approach to combining large numbers of tables and fields?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, ado

I need to select all the rows within *n* tables where *n* > 15 in ms access into a dataset. The single query results in an error, "Too many fields defined." My guess is that it surpasses the 255 field limit.

```
SELECT * FROM ((((((((((((((((Forms 
LEFT JOIN Layouts ON Layouts.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Layout ON Layout.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Form ON Form.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Sections ON Sections.ID] = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Checks ON Checks.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Dates ON Dates.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Combos ON Combos.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Labels ON Labels.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Flash ON Flash.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Links ON Links.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Groups ON Groups.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Lists ON Lists.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Pictures ON Pictures.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Grids ON Grids.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Shapes ON Shapes.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Texts ON Texts.ID = Form.ID) 
WHERE Forms.Name = 'History'
```

I've read from some SO users, this approach to accessing large amounts of columns/fields is inappropriate or bad practice. What would be the correct method or way of thinking to obtaining large amounts of fields where the many tables are all related?

Comment: Wow! That's a real STAR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your query is the `select *`, not the joins.  The joins are, presumably, fine if `Form.Id` is really the field you want to join on.

Instead, list the columns in the select:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 . . .
FROM ((((((((((((((((Forms 
LEFT JOIN Layouts ON Layouts.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Layout ON Layout.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Form ON Form.Name = Forms.Name) 
LEFT JOIN Sections ON Sections.ID] = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Checks ON Checks.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Dates ON Dates.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Combos ON Combos.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Labels ON Labels.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Flash ON Flash.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Links ON Links.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Groups ON Groups.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Lists ON Lists.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Pictures ON Pictures.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Grids ON Grids.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Shapes ON Shapes.ID = Form.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Texts ON Texts.ID = Form.ID) 
WHERE Forms.Name = 'History'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm needing all the fields within the tables, in this case should I still list out all the columns in my query? (in some situations certain tables are empty)

Comment: The reason why `SELECT * ` gives you an error and generally inappropirate here: it returns _All_ columns from _All_ tables being joined. If you want to select all columns from a particulaer table (which is not so good too) use `SELECT Layout.*, Grids.*`. Remember to create indexes on all columns mentioned above.

Comment: @ErnestSoeralaya . . . If you need more than 255 columns, then you have a problem.  You have a secondary problem that many column names are repeated (such as `id`), but that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: @ErnestSoeralaya, MS Access would have a limit on number of columns returned in a single query- this is what the error is about. If you do need all columns, then have a master query so every row can be identified from it: make up a "master" key for every row. Then have several queries sorted by all key columns to extract different parts of final table. Finaly place them side by side in Excel, because, again, Access has limit on number of columns. I don;t like this solution myself, but cannot think of any other way, unless you  can change the requirement, eg asking "what users do with it next"?

Comment: In my original program I inserted each table into the dataset each in its own seperate query. I thought it would be faster if I could combine everything into just one query. 

@GordonLinoff In cases such as these requiring more than 255 columns, when importing many tables into a dataset should this be split into individual queries?

Comment: @Stoleg Thank you for your response. You are correct, I am needing all the tables inserted into the dataset in order for the user to manipulate any of the values presented to him. From my understanding I would query for the required master keys and initialize them as local variables to use for individual queries for each table that I need inserted into my dataset?

Comment: From my experience no-one can efficiently handle so much of data. Users always "want to have all data, so they can decide". Suggest them several focused reports that will extract various parts of mega table.